# Ansible and Wget

Tags: ansible

I am trying to wget a file from a web server from within an Ansible playbook.

Here is the Ansible snippet:

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: true
  tasks:
  - name: Prepare Install folder
    sudo: true
    action: shell sudo mkdir -p /tmp/my_install/mysql/ && cd /tmp/my_install/mysql/
  - name: Download MySql
    sudo: true
    action: shell sudo wget http://{{ repo_host }}/MySQL-5.6.15-1.el6.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar
```

Invoking it via:

```
ansible-playbook my_3rparties.yml -l vsrv644 --extra-vars "repo_host=vsrv656" -K -f 10
```

It fails with the following:

```
Cannot write to `MySQL-5.6.15-1.el6.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar' (Permission denied).
FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/usr2/ihazan/vufroria_3rparties.retry

vsrv644                : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

When trying to do the command that fail via regular remote ssh to mimic what ansible would do, it doesn't work as follows:

```
-bash-4.1$ ssh ihazan@vsrv644 'cd /tmp/my_install/mysql && sudo wget http://vsrv656/MySQL-5.6.15-1.el6.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar'
Enter passphrase for key '/usr2/ihazan/.ssh/id_rsa': 
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

But I can solve it using -t as follows:

```
-bash-4.1$ ssh -t ihazan@vsrv644 'cd /tmp/my_install/mysql && sudo wget http://vsrv656/MySQL-5.6.15-1.el6.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar'
```

Then it works.

Is there a way to set the -t (pseudo tty option) on ansible?

P.S: I could solve it by editing the sudoers file as others propose but that is a manual step I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Don't use [shell](http://docs.ansible.com/shell_module.html)-module when there is specialized modules available. In your case:

Create directories with [file](http://docs.ansible.com/file_module.html)-module:

```
- name: create project directory {{ common.project_dir }}
  file: state=directory path={{ common.project_dir }}
```

Download files with [get_url](http://docs.ansible.com/get_url_module.html)-module:

```
- name: download sources
  get_url: url={{ opencv.url }} dest={{ common.project_dir }}/{{ opencv.file }}
```

Note the new module call syntax in the examples above.

If you have to use `sudo` with password remember to give `--ask-sudo-pass` when needed (see e.g. [Remote Connection Information](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_getting_started.html#remote-connection-information)).

Comment: FYI, all the links (except the Remote Connection Info one) are dead, here are available ones:
- shell module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/shell_module.html
- file module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/file_module.html#file-module
- get_url module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/get_url_module.html

And the docs uses a different syntax to what you have here, I'm not sure if it's still valid or will work but it's worth bearing in mind.

Answer (score 1):

In Ansible:

- [file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html) to manage files/directories
- [get_url](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-get-url-module) to download what you need
- become:yes to use sudo priviledges

See ansible documentation:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/modules_by_category.html

Comment: Updated link to all modules: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_module.html